# Сортировка двоичного (бинарного) дерева

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Хочу написать двоичное дерево для хранения строк. Как упрощенная задача - нужно отсортировать дерево на одном уровне. Т.е. просто отсортировать по одному символу буквы.

Допустим есть дерево

```
struct Node {
   Node * left; 
   Node * right;
   char c;
 }
```

Какие существую варианты балансировки (упорядочивания дерева). Выходит что должен существовать медленный вариант и быстрый но не очень качественный?

Я вижу следующий алгоритм. 1. Создаем линейный массив, методом вставки упорядочиваем его, обходя все дерево. (тут т.к. извесно что елементов будет не более 256, то массив можно заранее создать в стеке) 2. Делим массив пополам, посередине корень, узел слева-посередине(1/4) - левый елемент, узел справа-посередине(3/4) - правый елемент, для деток повторяем деление (можно рекурсией).

Какие существую варианты балансировки деревьев желательно с оценкой затратности алгоритма, может есть ссылка где всё до кучи собрано?

Comment: Честно - для хранения строк я бы использовал бор а не бинарное дерево. И вопрос балансировки сразу бы ушел

Comment: Кнут - Искусство Программирования, т.3. Глава 6 - Поиск

Comment: Кнут http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/K/KNUT_Donal%27d_Ervin/_Knut_D.E..html почитаю...

Comment: похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062138/%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0 получил ответ. Данный вопрос через неделю удалю.

Comment: Вот такое есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062138/%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0 Боюсь готовых алгоритмов тут не дадут.