# Балансировка бинарного дерева

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево, балансировка

Необходимо провести балансировку бинарного дерева без использования поля высоты для элемента. Вижу этот алгоритм так, что после каждой вставки элемента необходимо пробегаться по дереву и рекурсивно высчитывать высоты поддеревьев. Есть ли другие способы или идеи? Буду очень благодарен, если поможете с кодом.

p.s
Знаю, что неэффективно по времени, но задача состоит именно в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

- выполнить симметричный (inorder) обход дерева, складывая элемент в массив - он получится сортированным
- теперь взять средний элемент массива, построить бинарные деревья поиска для правой и левой половины и прицепить эти деревья к корню - среднему элементу. Если рекурсивно сделать то же самое для этих поддеревьев, будет идеальная балансировка.

Замечу, что по времени алгоритм линейный.

Comment: Необходимо провести балансировку именно в самом дереве - через стандартные повороты.

Comment: @MBo я, кстати задавал подобный вопрос на [SO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042112/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0), но он остался без ответа. А к такому ответу... я сам пришел. Думаю что это самый оптимальный алгоритм.

Comment: @nick_n_a Да, при наличии памяти - это самый лучший вариант. Он, кажется, описан в одной из старых книг по алгоритмам - вероятно, в Ахо-Хопкрофт.